# Will Google Pay approve using the Offers vertical for digital certification cards?

Tags: google-pay

We are an eLearning company that provides certification courses online. We're looking to develop digital wallet integrations to provide proof of certifications on mobile phones.

The closest pass vertical for Google Pay is the Offers vertical. I designed a test class in the Merchant centre anticipating a manual review by Google, but when I changed the status to under review, it went immediately to approved.

Does this indicate that pass review is automatic, and our use case will be supported? I don't want to go through the development process, integrating with their API, if there is a chance our digital certificates will be reviewed and rejected.

Comment: It's not clear which APIs you are referring to. Can you include a link to the APIs you are referencing?

Comment: The Google Pay Passes REST API https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/rest